# Setting session factory

Tags: nservicebus

How can i inject the current session factory that is used by the nservice bus to a custom saga finder?

I have initialized the saga using the following code

```
NServiceBus.Configure.With()
                .CastleWindsorBuilder()
                .Sagas()
                .NHibernateSagaPersister()
                .XmlSerializer();
```

and i have a sagafinder

```
public sagafinder:saga<...>
{
 private ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public virtual ISessionFactory SessionFactory
        {
            get { return sessionFactory; }
            set { sessionFactory = value; }
        }
}
```

but this session factory is always coming as null.
I know i am not setting the session factory.How can i set it?

Thanks,
Ajai

Comment: Since you are using the NH persister, this will handle finding the Saga for you as long as you override the ConfigureHowToFindSaga() method in your implementation of Saga<T>.  Can you comment on how your situation is not met by the built-in mechanisms?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the age of this post I'm going to assume that you are using a pre-3 version of NServiceBus like 2.6.

I have been looking into this and writing Saga Finders for the built in  NHibernateSagaPersister is a hard problem.

The NHibernateSagaFinder uses an Ilmerged version of NHibernate that has been baked into NServiceBus.Core.dll. So when you write the following (ripped from the default saga finder):

```
public class MySagaFinder : IFindSagas<MySaga>
{
    public NHibernate.ISession Session {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

The ISession here will refer to the one in NHibernate.dll you have referrenced not NServiceBus's internal NHibernate. As far as I can tell it is not possible to reference NServiceBus.Core's NHibernate as it is "internal". This means that the IOC container that NServiceBus uses will either not inject a session or will inject the wrong one depending how you have it set up.

I have been looking into this for a while now and I think the best (only) thing to do is create your own custom SagaFinder based on the NServiceBus's built in one. This should not be to hard to do as it is in the code base on GitHub.

This may be fixed with later version of NServiceBus (>=3) but I'm not sure as I think they now use RavenDB for thier default saga persistance.

Answer (score 0):

the code in the question does not look like a saga finder at all.  what i see is a saga itself instead.  if you are just trying to find the saga based on some property in the message, adam's suggestion is the correct one.  you don't need the session factory and should just override ConfigureHowToFindSaga().  if you are trying to do something else, it is true that the session factory used by the nhibernate saga persister is not registered up with your container such that you can just resolve the dependency in your saga.  chances are slim that you'd really want to query the saga stored yourself, though.  so, if you really have a reason for it, i'd probably just suggest you register a session factory yourelf for the database with the saga information and let nservicebus have its own.  hard to imagine you'd really want to, though.